# API: _pk (Primary key) Integration in python

Tags: python, primary-key

I am trying to integrate an API with Python.
The final result I am looking for is to obtain a list of revisions depending on what schematization is clicked (which is specified in another parameter).

The API data organization follows this root:

```
   GET /v3/schematisations/7956/revisions
```

Where the number between schematisations and revisions corresponds to the _pk of the schematisation (It is the same as the id, but it program doesn't identify the id as the _pk).

To ask the API for the information I am using this code:

```
   revisions = self.api_client.schematisations_revisions_list()
```

But when coding the integration, I obtain this error:

> TypeError: schematisations_revisions_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'schematisation_pk'

I tried:
defining _pk in the:

```
   def updateParameters(self, parameters):
```

to make a list of the schematisations_pk to filter it.
To make a list of the id numbers and match them with the schematisations

I keep obtaining the same error

Comment: When I do put in the id number in the schematisation revision list parenthesis it does recognize it, but need it as a list, bot just one of the ids